# «В том числе»: как правильно употреблять?

Tags: синтаксис, лексика, грамматика, вводные-слова

Итак, несколько вопросов:

> В этой энциклопедии есть в том числе ответ на твой вопрос.

Употребление «в том числе» таким образом, то есть вне присоединительного оборота, некорректно или всё-таки допустимо, хотя бы в разговорной речи?

> — Он гражданин России.
>  — В том числе России.

Корректна ли вторая реплика в данном диалоге? Можно ли словами «в том числе» дополнить высказывание говорящего, если он упомянул частность и упустил, по твоему мнению, еще что-то важное?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое употребление **некорректно**, в лучшем случае *просторечно*. Его ответ был бы уместен после высказывания "*Он гражданин нескольких стран...*".

Словарь Ефремовой:

> Употребляется при присоединении члена предложения, который является
> частью того целого, о котором идет речь в первой части предложения;
> включая кого-л., что-л., в том числе и.

Примеры из учебного фразеологического словаря (Е. А. Быстрова, А. П. Окунева, Н. М. Шанский. 1997):

> Выдающийся русский
> композитор П. И. Чайковский – автор *десяти опер, в том числе* таких
> всемирно известных, как «Евгений Онегин», «Пиковая дама», «Иоланта».
>
> Необходимо… чтобы сохранялись национальные культуры, *языки, в том*
> *числе и русский язык*. (В. Распутин.)

Говорящий путает по способу употребления выражения "**в том числе**" и "**в частности**". Скорее всего, второе выражение в его речи начисто отсутствует, а ответить "в числе прочих (стран)", "включая Россию" и т. п. ему затруднительно.

К величайшему сожалению, такое употребление выражения "в том числе" распространилось за последние примерно 15 лет, по моим наблюдениям, из агрессивной политической риторики в телевизионных ток-шоу типа вечерней программы известного пропагандиста, в котором приглашенные кричат и перебивают друг друга, а в качестве аргумента вставляют в свою речь
выражение "в том числе", причем в значении "то, что я сказал, - не единственный мой аргумент (надо будет - еще добавлю)". Выражение "в том числе" они произносят вторым китайским тоном, с угрожающим подвыванием на слоге "том".

На мой взгляд, это одна из болезней языка современной журналистики, которая перекинулась на значительную часть её аудитории. Люди перестали замечать, что говорят недопустимым образом. Фотомодель Водянова на вопрос, смотрела ли она такой-то фильм, ответила "в том числе" - уже трудно стало винить людей в синдроме Эллочки-людоедки, но словари, к счастью, не спешат фиксировать эту аномалию как норму.

Comment: Блестящий ответ!

Answer (score 2):

К ответу можно добавить следующее.

Не стоит противопоставлять сочетания ***в частности*** и ***в том числе***.  Вводное слово ***в частности*** может также выступать в роли присоединительного союза. Нужно просто следить за тем, чтобы в предыдущем тексте было  упомянуто **целое,** по отношению к которому рассматривается часть. Это требование для обоих вариантов.

Примеры:

В этой энциклопедии можно найти ответы на многие вопросы по этой теме. **В том числе/ в частности** там есть ответ на твой вопрос.

— Он гражданин России?

— И России тоже.

Здесь в  диалоге тема не раскрывается полностью, поэтому нужна другая грамматика.

— Он гражданин России.

— Он гражданин разных государств,  **в том числе/в частности** России.

Из Справочника:

**В ТОМ ЧИСЛЕ, союз**

Приезжает генерал; дрожащий смотритель отдает ему две последние тройки, **в том числе** курьерскую. А. Пушкин, Станционный смотритель.

**В ЧАСТНОСТИ, вводное слово**

Я тоже привык записывать свои мысли на чём попало, **в частности** на папиросных коробках. К. Паустовский, Золотая роза.

Comment: Я считаю _ошибкой_ (она малозаметна на фоне современных чудес из телевизора) пример с "энциклопедией": "в частности" годится, а "в том числе" (в начале нового предложения) - нет. Этот союз, в отличие от а/и, не может "присоединять" законченные предложения. Возможный вариант: "_В этой энциклопедии можно найти ответы на многие вопросы по этой теме, в том числе и на твой вопрос".

Comment: Почему же не может? Это обычная парцелляция - намеренное расчленение связного текста на  самостоятельные отрезки. Сделана пауза (чуть больше, чем при запятой), а дальше мысль продолжена.

Comment: По определению (напр. у той же Ефремовой), "в том числе" присоединяет _члены предложения_, а не предложение со своим глаголом (думаю, не спасла бы и запятая вместо точки). Смысл "того числа" почти буквален, это не идиома. Присоединяется конкретно "твой вопрос" к (числу) "многих вопросов по этой теме". "В частности" же позволяет приводить _любое_ по форме высказывание как частный случай предыдущего. Мнимая взаимозаменяемость одного и другого в свое время привела к более серьезным аномалиям. Процитировав словари, вы правильно противопоставили две **разные части речи**.

Comment: Alex_ander, вы меня, наверное, не поняли. Это - парцелляция, а в этом случае деление на части свободное, оно делается не по словарям, а по желанию автора.

Comment: Автор может намеренно поиздеваться над грамматикой (мол читатель сам расставит слова правильно) но обычно следит за тем, чтобы этот факт был заметен. Но вы же приводите пример образцовой речи.

Comment: Это у вас в Питере образцовая речь, а у нас всё больше разговорная (шутка). Согласитесь, что сочетание "образцовая разговорная речь" звучит странно.

Comment: А попробуйте найти подобную "разговорность" у персонажей русской классики (за Прилепина или позднюю Донцову не ручаюсь).

Comment: Хорошо, если найду, то вам сообщу.